# How to make a div disappear after a certain distance using condition "if" (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I tried to move a block to 200 px on the right (this part is fine)

```js
function blue() {
    document.getElementById("blue").style.transform = "translate(200px)";
    document.getElementById("blue").style.transition = "0.5s";
}
```

```css
#blue{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2rem;
    background-color: rgb(133, 133, 134);
}
```

```html
        <div id="blue"></div>
        
        <button onclick="blue()">right</button>
```

but I add an IF: if it's more than 200 px it should disappear. The problem is that is disappear anyway regardless of the px.

```js
function blue() {
    document.getElementById("blue").style.transform = "translate(200px)";
    document.getElementById("blue").style.transition = "0.5s";
    
    if(document.getElementById("blue").style.transform = "translate(200px)" > "200px"){
        document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "none";
    } else
    {
        document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function appear(){
    document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
#blue{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2rem;
    background-color: rgb(133, 133, 134);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
       
<button onclick="blue()">right</button>

<button onclick="appear()">make it appears</button>
```

My condition:

```
 if(document.getElementById("blue").style.transform = "translate(200px)" > "200px")
```

seems wrong, how can I write it?

Comment: That is setting the transform to equal the result of a string greater than a string It is unclear what exactly you are trying to check so hard to tell. Are you trying to figure out the value of transform? Is there a reason why you are not just toggling a class?

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` or `===` is an equality. Also `= "translate(200px)" > "200px"` is going to try comparing strings using `>`, which doesn't seem like what you are aiming for.

Comment: @epascarello I try to make a sort of carousel with div, and this is the first step (I'm not good so I tried something but it didn't work), I will think about using  class

Comment: @DBS thank you, it was a mistake to not use ==

Answer (score 1):

First we select the element and store the current position of the element. Then we set a listener `ontransistioned()` which is fired after the element's transition has occurred. When the listener function is fired, we determine the difference between the old position and the new position. If this difference is greater equal 200, we set the `display` property to `"none"`.

```js
function blue() {
    const elem = document.getElementById("blue");
    const oldPos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
   
    elem.ontransitionend = () => {
      const newPos = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
      const diff = Math.abs(oldPos.x - newPos.x)
      if (diff >= 200) 
        elem.style.display = "none";
    };

    elem.style.transform = "translate(200px)";
    elem.style.transition = "0.5s";
    
}

function appear(){
    document.getElementById("blue").style.display = "block"
}
```

```css
#blue{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2rem;
    background-color: rgb(133, 133, 134);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
       
<button onclick="blue()">right</button>

<button onclick="appear()">make it appears</button>
```